# IP in the configuration file is not updated when we restart any redis pod in bitani kubernetes redis-cluster

Tags: kubernetes, redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

I am using bitnami redis-clusters' helm charts(version 6.3.6). When I restart any pod, the new IP of the pod is not updated automatically on **nodes.conf** located in `/bitnami/redis/data/` . So the new pod seems to be not coming to a fully running state. Any solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest version of **bitnami redis-clusters'** solves it.